# How do I set the style of the "text" rendered from :after{content:"text"}?

Tags: css

I have a `<a>` tag and with a `a:after{content:"(1)"}` I can add a text `(1)` after it. But what if I want to set the color, font of the `(1)`? Is it possible?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tired anything? This is very easily solved simply by trying to add styles to your after rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `color` property to do so:

```
a:after{content:"(1)"; color:red;}
```

Working example:http://jsfiddle.net/f2z8ztvc/

Answer (score 1):

Styling a pseudo-element in CSS is often no different than styling a regular element. The main difference is in the selector, and where the styles will be applied.

The spec describes which CSS properties apply to which pseudo-elements, but for the purposes of this question the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements behave exactly like their regular counterparts (interestingly, [CSS2.1 mentions this explicitly](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#pseudo-element-selectors), but [Selectors 3 doesn't](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)). So if you want to change the font of your `:after` pseudo-element, there is nothing stopping you from doing so.